# How to use a variable (for wordpress postid) in other queries?

Tags: php

I don't know php, I just edit it for my needs, please excuse my possible mis-use of terms. I think the fact I am searching for the wrong terms has made this difficult to find a solution for, which is why I am asking.

Basically I need to define a postid, then use it multiple ways.

```
$number = 455;
```

So above you can see the number of a postid.

Then within my templates I am using it as follows.

```
echo get_the_permalink( '$number' );
```

How do I make that work?

```
echo get_the_permalink( '455' );
```

^ works fine, but it means me typing that id a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the variable, don't use the quotes. So it would be like:

```
echo get_the_permalink( $number );
```

You can also use:

```
echo get_permalink( $number );
```

or:

```
the_permalink( $number )
```

*get_the_permalink()* is an alias for *get_permalink()*.

Comment: ha, simple as that. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!